# How to change fields in object in array by id in mongoose partially?

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose

How to change partially fields in an object in the array by id in mongoose?
I need to change the question and answer in one object 'cards'. How can I do that?

my strange attempt:

```
const game = await Game.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: cardId, cards._id: itemQuestionId }, { $set: { 
        cards.$.question: questionEdit, 
        cards.$.answer: answerEdit
    }
}).lean()
```

Document structure -

```
{
    "theme": "Игра престолов",
    "cards": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ae1e78956ee2a72057c87f"
        },
        "question": "Мастера монет Лорда Петра Баелиша также знали под каким именем?",
        "answer": "Мизинец",
        "points": 100
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ae1e78956ee2a72057c880"
        },
        "question": "Что изображено на гербе Ланнистеров?",
        "answer": "Лев",
        "points": 200
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ae1e78956ee2a72057c881"
        },
        "question": "Как зовут Лютоволка Джона Сноу?",
        "answer": "Призрак",
        "points": 300
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ae1e78956ee2a72057c882"
        },
        "question": "Кто был ответственным за создание Ночного Короля?",
        "answer": "дети леса",
        "points": 400
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60ae1e78956ee2a72057c883"
        },
        "question": "Чёрно-белый дом служит ещё и храмом. А кому там поклоняются?",
        "answer": "Многоликому",
        "points": 500
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

On the internet I found solutions  only for MongoDB, I need for Mongoose

Comment: Questions and answers here have to be written **only** in English, not a mix of languages. If you need help in Russian, please use http://ru.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The filter query seems to be correct according to the [`syntax`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I did it

```
app.patch("/api/v1/games/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const {questionEdit, answerEdit, itemQuestionId, cardId} = req.body;

const game = await Game.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: cardId},
  {$set: {"cards.$[el].question": questionEdit } },
  { 
    arrayFilters: [{ "el._id":  itemQuestionId}],
    new: true
  }
)
.........................rest code
});
```